# Generating a bash script with echo, problem with shebang line

Tags: bash, echo, shebang

I want to explain to some friends how to add multikey support to their linux systems at bootup but first I need them to make a bash script. I want to make a simple command for them to copy and paste and I'm testing out this command I made but it keeps throwing an error. Only when I add the shebang line which, well is important.

```
$ sudo echo -e "#!/bin/bash \nxmodmap \"keysym Alt_R = Multi_key\"" > /etc.init.d/multikey.sh
```

Any easy way to echo a shebang line?

Comment: nevermind, found out I just needed to use a raw string, ie ''

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use the other quotes.

```
sudo echo -e '#!/bin/bash\nxmodmap "keysym Alt_R = Multi_key"'
```

Answer (score 16):

If you want to impress your friends use here documents not echo strings :-)

```
~$ cat << EOF > /etc/init.d/multikey.sh
> #!/bin/bash          
> xmodmap "keysym Alt_R = Multi_key"
> EOF
```